# send mail by using php5

Tags: php, email, sendmail

i wish to send form data throw mailto() in php,
but i got an warning msg that "Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in
 C:\xampp\htdocs\

please sugest me that what i have to do for send data to a mail id properly

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the raw `mail()` function, with which you'll have to do everything yourself, it would probably be better to learn how to use a component such as [**swift mailer**](http://swiftmailer.org/).

It might take a bit of time to go through the documentation, but it provides a lot a useful features that you'll be able to re-use accross different projects *(like HTML, attached documents, mailling via a remote SMTP server, ...)*

Note : there are several great mail components available -- swift is one of them, which is sued in Frameworks such as Symfony, and, as such, should be well-supported.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems that you are on windows the most easy way is to seman mail trough a smtp server.
For that you can use the mail class from Pear -> http://pear.php.net/package/Mail

Answer (score 0):

PHP needs a mail server to deliver messages. In your php.ini file you'll find this directive:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = smtp.example.com
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
sendmail_from = webmaster@example.com
```

Edit the file and fill the values with your e-mail provider information.